# Java Script error - can't convert undefined to object

Tags: javascript, undefined

I get "can't convert undefined to object" error while trying to run this piece of code. I'm not a programmer and can barely code therefore my question might be quite stupid/unanswerable for what I'm deeply sorry.

Code:

```
if (path == F[0])
    {
        //go N
        if (pointAy > 0) 
        {
            if (!(PS.BeadData(pointAx, pointAy - 1) === "blocked")) 
            {
                // Set bead to Previous State
                PS.BeadColor(pointAx, pointAy, previous_bead_NPC[NPCid][2]);
                PS.BeadData(pointAx, pointAy, 0);
                PS.BeadGlyph(pointAx, pointAy, " ");                 
                // Increment
                pointAy -= 1;
                // Place NPC
                MakeNPC(pointAx, pointAy, NPC[NPCid][2], NPC[NPCid][3], NPC[NPCid][4], NPC[NPCid][5], 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can't really tell if this is enough to find an answer for you - I can post more of the code if it would help.

Maybe there is some generic answer to such an error a normal programmer would know, but such a noob like me will be oblivious to?

UPDATE
Ok, through step-by-step execution I found out that the error pops out in a different function even though disabling above piece of code makes the error not pop up. This is the function that makes the error pop up:

```
PS.Tick = function ()
{
"use strict";
for (var NPCid = 0; NPCid < 10; NPCid++)
    {
        NPCAI(NPCid);
    };
};
```

This function is called every second and it calls AI logic function to move 10 NPC on a grid by supplying the NPCid to the AI function. Script fails here, but not always - usually one or two of the NPCs makes a step and only then the function fails.

Comment: Which line are you getting this error?

Comment: Could be that `PS` is `undefined`.

Comment: PS is defined... I think. Its part of an engine I did not wrote and it works elsewhere.

Comment: I'm trying to find the line that gives the error with firebug, but I have no idea how to do it:(

Comment: Definitely looks as though either `PS` or `NCP` is undefined. You can easily confirm this by `console.log()`'ing both before this code runs.

Comment: There are two 2d Arrays with NPC data: NPC and previous_bead_NPC. First contains data about an NPC. The second one contains data of a bead (location) on which the NPC is currently so it can be restored to its original condition when NPC leaves that bead. Problem is that in Firebug I have the NPC array listed but the previous_bead_NPC array is absent. Maybe its not properly defined?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome or Firebug you can step through the JavaScript code.  On Chrome, open up the tools icon (wrench in the upper right corner), then enable the developer tools by selecting "Tools" from the drop down menu and the "Developer Tools".  At the bottom you should see a button in the lower part of your screen for scripts.  Click on that and navigate to your page.  When you see your JavaScript file open it and put a breakpoint at the "if" statement.  Reload your page and then look at the values of PS and NPC when the debugger stops your code.